# How can I get the data when I click the place order button on the checkout page of the magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How can I get the data when I click the **place order** button on the checkout page of the Magento 2?
When clicking button place order, show the output data like `var_dump ($data); die ();` so as not to redirect to checkout success.
Thank you so much.
[image: Checkout One Page]

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension and modify as per your requirement.
 
1 https://github.com/navinbhudiya/magento2-order-details-on-success-page 
2 https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-order-details-on-success-page.html

Comment: Hi Biren Patel,
I want var_dump data immediately after submitting, and the data show shows that current checkout page.
Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

Following class is responsible for placing the order.

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

And method:

> savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder

You can debug here. This is api class and you can't get data as $data. All data are passes here as an object.

Also, you can throw an exception here for avoiding success page.